# IOS issue with ActionCable not delivering messages

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

We have noticed, that **IOS** users with version **17.0.x** while using the **ActionCable** on **Rails** almost 50% of the messages were not delivered.

We are getting the following messages.

```
D 2023-10-06T07:21:42.075Z context=node sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Perform result: &{[] false [] false []}
D 2023-10-06T07:21:42.198Z context=node sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"action":"read"}}
W 2023-10-06T07:21:42.198Z context=node sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Unknown subscription {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512}
D 2023-10-06T07:25:48.772Z context=node sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Websocket close error: websocket: close 1006 (abnormal closure): unexpected EOF
D 2023-10-06T07:25:48.772Z context=node sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK websocket session completed
D 2023-10-06T07:25:48.772Z channel={"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"} context=hub sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Unsubscribed             
D 2023-10-06T07:25:48.772Z context=hub sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Unregistered             
D 2023-10-06T07:25:48.772Z context=node sid=kNJYv6SokFfI9dy9T1E9mK Disconnect {"current_user":"Z2lkOi8vbXlqb2Jub3cvVXNlci8zMzY4"} /cable [{"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"}]
D 2023-10-06T07:25:48.774Z context=rpc Disconnect response: status:SUCCESS 
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.129Z context=rpc Authenticate response: status:SUCCESS identifiers:"{\"current_user\":\"Z2lkOi8vbXlqb2Jub3cvVXNlci8zMzY4\"}" transmissions:"{\"type\":\"welcome\"}" 
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.129Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg websocket session established
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.129Z context=hub sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Registered with identifiers: {"current_user":"Z2lkOi8vbXlqb2Jub3cvVXNlci8zMzY4"}
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.348Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{subscribe {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} }
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.354Z context=rpc Command response: status:SUCCESS streams:"conversation_1512" transmissions:"{\"identifier\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"ConversationChannel\\\",\\\"conversation_id\\\":1512}\",\"type\":\"confirm_subscription\"}" 
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.354Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Subscribed to channel: {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512}
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.354Z channel={"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} context=hub sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg stream=conversation_1512 Subscribed               
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.426Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"action":"read"}}
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.447Z context=rpc Command response: status:SUCCESS 
D 2023-10-06T07:26:50.447Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Perform result: &{[] false [] false []}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:05.902Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"text":"Dsdwasdad","uuid":"EFFFEADD-40D3-4D68-8E39-1303F7E68B30","action":"send_message"}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:05.994Z context=pubsub Incoming pubsub message from Redis: {"stream":"conversation_1512","data":"{\"action\":\"new_message\",\"payload\":{\"msg\":{\"text\":\"Dsdwasdad\"}}}"}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:05.994Z context=node Incoming pubsub message: &{conversation_1512 {"action":"new_message","payload":{"msg":{"text":"Dsdwasdad",}}}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:05.994Z context=hub stream=conversation_1512 Broadcast message: {"action":"new_message","payload":{"msg":{"text":"Dsdwasdad",}}}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:05.997Z context=rpc Command response: status:SUCCESS 
D 2023-10-06T07:27:05.997Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Perform result: &{[] false [] false []}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:06.130Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"action":"read"}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:06.150Z context=rpc Command response: status:SUCCESS 
D 2023-10-06T07:27:06.150Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Perform result: &{[] false [] false []}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:07.824Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"} {"uuid":"D192F95C-C20E-4B12-9D83-9076EE9CA378","text":"Dasdw","action":"send_message"}}
W 2023-10-06T07:27:07.824Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Unknown subscription {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:10.754Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"} {"text":"Dassss","uuid":"1FD4DF7F-6DD1-4326-AA50-87CFA917C7A7","action":"send_message"}}
W 2023-10-06T07:27:10.754Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Unknown subscription {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.166Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"uuid":"E4053CD5-A614-4D51-8927-5D3E6D611875","text":"Dddwdwa","action":"send_message"}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.239Z context=pubsub Incoming pubsub message from Redis: {"stream":"conversation_1512","data":"{\"action\":\"new_message\",\"payload\":{\"msg\":{\"text\":\"Dddwdwa\",}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.239Z context=node Incoming pubsub message: &{conversation_1512 {"action":"new_message","payload":{"msg":{"text":"Dddwdwa""conversation_id":1512,"timestamp":"2023-10-06T07:27:13+00:00","uuid":"E4053CD5-A614-4D51-8927-5D3E6D611875","type":{"name":"text","text":"Dddwdwa"}}}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.239Z context=hub stream=conversation_1512 Broadcast message: {"action":"new_message","payload":{"msg":{"text":"Dddwdwa","conversation_id":1512,"timestamp":"2023-10-06T07:27:13+00:00","uuid":"E4053CD5-A614-4D51-8927-5D3E6D611875","type":{"name":"text","text":"Dddwdwa"} }}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.241Z context=rpc Command response: status:SUCCESS 
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.241Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Perform result: &{[] false [] false []}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.375Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"action":"read"}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.396Z context=rpc Command response: status:SUCCESS 
D 2023-10-06T07:27:13.396Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Perform result: &{[] false [] false []}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:16.662Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"} {"action":"send_message","uuid":"E5618963-1CA1-4EB3-BAB9-196590F35A7B","text":"Asdwadasdwa"}}
W 2023-10-06T07:27:16.662Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Unknown subscription {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:26.078Z context=node sid=mAfQYjytdw5yO1QHHTJ1dg Incoming message: &{message {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512} {"text":"Dsdsds\n","uuid":"C52C1FA9-B495-44C4-B4E4-2A8D97AEE4B9","action":"send_message"}}
D 2023-10-06T07:27:26.153Z context=pubsub Incoming pubsub message from Redis: {"stream":"conversation_1512","data":"{\"action\":\"new_message\",\"payload\":{\"msg\":{\"text\":\"Dsdsds\\n\"}
```

A screenshot from the test performed attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx442.png)

As a results, **those messages not delivered to IOS users.**

### Library Versions

Server Side : **Rails v6,AnyCable v0.6.5**

IOS Lib for Client Websocket: **Starscream** (initially on v3.1.1), then on v4.0.6 issue persists.

We have pinpointed that the issue might be on the IOS version, as on previous versions **16.x, 15.x** is working without any issue.Moreover, on Android and Web clients there is no issue at all.

Any insights/suggestions will be really helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
Subscribed to channel: {"channel":"ConversationChannel","conversation_id":1512}

...

Unknown subscription {"conversation_id":1512,"channel":"ConversationChannel"}
```

The order of the fields in the identifier (which is the JSON-encoded object) is different.

AnyCable treats identifiers as strings, it has no assumptions on what's inside (i.e., we don't decode JSON to look up a channel). See the [protocol spec](https://docs.anycable.io/misc/action_cable_protocol?id=subscriptions-amp-identifiers).

Which client-side library do you use? It seems that it doesn't re-use the identifier and instead performs JSON encoding of the `{channel, conversation_id}` object every time it sends a command—which is wrong.

Also,

> AnyCable v0.6.5

Is it a gem version? Anyway, it's too old (though not related, I think)

Comment: So, the identifier is a JSON string inside another JSON string and AnyCable decodes the outer JSON string but not the inner JSON string? Do I have this right?

Comment: Correct. AnyCable server has no assumptions regarding the identifier; from its perspective it's just a string (and it must be the same for all commands within a subscription). It's decided by the application server if it must be a JSON string or whatever.